# Terminate A Thread, Running Code Before Exit

Tags: multithreading, delphi, terminate

I want to be able to terminate a thread on the click of a button, e.g., stop the process half-way through if the user wants. Apparently, you can do this by mointoring for Terminated variable in the thread, which means you can then excute some code before exiting rather than abruptly terminating.

The code so far is as follows :-

Start Thread On Click

```
procedure TForm1.Panel29Click(Sender: TObject);
var
cmpfil : TThread;

begin
  if (Edit3.Text <> '') AND (Edit4.Text <> '') then
  begin
    Form1.ProgressBar1.Min := 0;
    Form1.Progressbar1.Max := 30000;
    Form1.ProgressBar1.Position := 0;
    cmpfiles := TCompareFilesThread.Create();
  end;
end;
```

Create Thread

```
constructor TCompareFilesThread.Create;
begin
  inherited Create(False);
end;
```

Actual Thread

```
procedure TCompareFilesThread.Execute;
var
  forg, fpat : file;
  byteorg, bytepat : Array[0..1023] of byte;
  i,z,o : integer;
  fil1,fil2 : TFilename;
begin
  //Form1.CompareFiles(FEdit3Text, FEdit4Text, FGrid, FOp, FProg);

  begin
    fil1 := Form1.Edit3.Text;
    fil2 := Form1.Edit4.Text;
    if Form1.CRCAdlerGenFile(fil1,1) <> Form1.CRCAdlerGenFile(fil2,1) then //Only Run if files arn't same
    begin
      op := 3;
      synchronize(SetOP);

      i := 0;
      x := 1;
      o := 0;

      AssignFile(forg,fil1);
      FileMode := fmOpenRead;
      Reset(forg,1);
      AssignFile(fpat,fil2);
      FileMode := fmOpenRead;
      Reset(fpat,1);

      //Set Progress Bar

      while NOT eof(forg) do
      begin
        while Terminated = False do
        begin
          BlockRead(forg,byteorg,1024);
          BlockRead(fpat,bytepat,1024);

          for z := 0 to 1023 do
          begin
            if byteorg[z] <> bytepat[z] then
            begin
              synchronize(sProgBarNext);
              by := bytepat[z];
              off := IntToStr(o);
              synchronize(SyncGrid);
              inc(x);
            end;
            inc(o);
          end;
        end;
      end;

      CloseFile(forg);
      CloseFile(fpat);
    end;
  end;
  Free;
end;
```

I've already added the `While Terminated = False do` line which will stop the process when that is changed. I just can't seem to figure out how to change it. I never created that variable; it's the built-in Delphi feature. I have read about `TMyThread.Terminate()` however I can't seem to find out exactly what that does. Does it set Terminated to True or will it just kill the thread where it stands?

P.S. I haven't posted the code from the synchronized routines. One prints to StringGrid, one updates ProgressBar and the third sets an op variable which is used by the StringGrid Sync routine, and I don't see this code as being relevant to the problem, however I can post if requested.

Comment: `s/digress/ramble on incessantly/` :-)

Comment: After reading the documentation for `TThread.Terminate`, where it says "Terminate sets the thread's Terminated property to true, signaling that the thread should be terminated as soon as possible," why did you continue to wonder what it does? Also, remember you have the source code. If you want to know what it does, open *Classes.pas* and look.

Comment: Those calls to Synchronize are liable to be astoundingly costly. Why don't you just write the information to an integer, make sure its aligned on a 4 byte boundary, and get your main thread to read it periodically on a timer and update the UI that way. You'll lose all the benefit of threading if you spend time in your thread synchronising!

Comment: @Rob Kennedy I had read that documentation and that is where the confusion arose. I found another question on here that talked about it as well but it should `TThread.Terminate` will kill the thread instantly so thought I better check to be safe. @David Heffernan Nice idea, thanks :)

Comment: Which other question told you `TThread.Terminate` will kill the thread? Are you sure it said `TThread.Terminate`, and not `TerminateThread`? The latter is the Windows API function, and it *will* kill a thread immediately. They're completely different functions, and they're called differently.

Comment: You may well be right and I was mistaken. I'll try and find the question again to check since it was a Google result rather than an internal search.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, call [Terminate](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Classes.TThread.Terminate) on your thread object.  It sets `Terminated` to true, and that's all it does - your thread needs to check for `Terminated`, as your code is doing (although there's a bug, see below.)

In more detail: you create your thread object here:

```
cmpfiles := TCompareFilesThread.Create();
```

Make `cmpfiles` a member variable of your form or another class, not local to your `Panel29Click` procedure.  Initialise it to `nil` in the constructor.  Then when you need to cancel, call:

```
if Assigned(cmpfiles) then begin
  cmpfiles.Terminate;
end;
```

This sets the Terminated flag if the thread exists.  (Edit: thanks Rob, who suggested avoiding FreeOnTerminate.  It was bad advice of mine to suggest using it in the first place.)  Your thread also needs to notify your main thread when its finished, right at the end of Execute, so that you can free it.  One way to do this is to use [`Synchronize`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Classes.TThread.Synchronize) to notify the main thread, and then in the main thread in the method you pass to `Synchronize` you can free the thread object.

```
FreeAndNil(cmpfiles);
```

Do this *at the very end* of `Execute` because the thread object will be deleted - you don't want any more code to run.

**One bug I spotted:**  Your `Execute` code has the following two while loops:

```
while NOT eof(forg) do
begin
   while Terminated = False do
      begin
         ...
      end;
end;
```

This will actually loop while not terminated, and it will only check if it's at the end of the file once `Terminated` is set to `true`.  You probably want your loop to check both conditions at the same time, something like:

```
while (not eof(forg) and not Terminated) do
begin
   ...
end;
```

Oh, and **another bug**, your thread code accesses Form1's data:

```
if Form1.CRCAdlerGenFile(fil1,1) <> Form1.CRCAdlerGenFile(fil2,1) then //Only Run if files arn't same
```

What is this code, running a CRC on the files?  If the `CRCAdlerGenFile` function doesn't actually touch any part of Form1 and it only relies on its parameters (and they're standalone), make this either a helper function somewhere - it doesn't have to be part of a class, you can have standalone functions.  If it does rely on parts of Form1, you shouldn't be calling it from your thread code.

Comment: Thanks for the help :) Nice spot on the bugs too. The first bug was untested code for example so I will work on that. The second originally accessed data from the Form, however it was since updated to not use the Form however I just haven't got round to removing it from the class yet ;)

Comment: Please don't set `FreeOnTerminate := True` and then continue to refer to the object from outside the thread class. At any moment, the reference may become invalid. It's the "set it and forget it" property, so if you can't forget it, don't set it.

Comment: Yes... if it succeeds without canceling, cmpfiles will be invalid.  TheFlatline, instead of FreeOnTerminate have your thread notify the main thread when it's one, and free it (and nullify your variable) there.  That way you know cmpfiles is always valid.